# Multi dimension array formatting

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

i want to echo the array value with the key of `type` , here is my code,

```
foreach ($sam as $key => $sa) {
    foreach ($sa as $s) {
        echo $s['type'];
    }
}
```

and this is the content of array `$sam`

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=5)
      'type' => string 'days' (length=4)
      'bookable' => string 'no' (length=2)
      'priority' => int 10
      'from' => string '1' (length=1)
      'to' => string '1' (length=1)
```

my serier of foreach code results **Warning: Illegal string offset 'type'** and i dont know why? can you help me echo `type` thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need one foreach:

```
foreach ($sam as $s) {
    echo $s['type'];
}
```